# Efficient sampling from a 'partial' binomial distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random, binomial-cdf

I am want to sample from the binomial distribution B(n,p) but with an additional constraint that the sampled value belongs in the range [a,b] (instead of the normal 0 to n range). In other words, I have to sample a value from binomial distribution given that it lies in the range [a,b]. Mathematically, I can write the pmf of this distribution (`f(x)`) in terms of the pmf of binomial distribution `bin(x) = [(nCx)*(p)^x*(1-p)^(n-x)]` as

```
sum = 0
for i in range(a,b+1):
    sum += bin(i)

f(x) = bin(x)/sum
```

One way of sampling from this distribution is to sample a uniformly distributed number and apply the inverse of the CDF(obtained using the pmf). However, I don't think this is a good idea as the pmf calculation would easily get very time-consuming.

The values of `n,x,a,b`  are quite large in my case and this way of computing pmf and then using a uniform random variable to generate the sample seems extremely inefficient due to the factorial terms in `nCx`.

What's a nice/efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: i thought the range of binomial distribution has to be from 0 to n. can you provide me a link for the further math behind this question? I wanna read about this little more.

Comment: In addition, if you are having trouble with optimizing your code, I recommend you to use NumPy to vectorize your calculation. it's 100x faster than a for-loop

Comment: I've found a bug-free and effective solution which allows to calculate `pmf` and `cdf` for millions of items. It requires to use `scipy.stats.binom`. This is a new thing for me because I knew so far only a `scipy.special.comb` which is misleading.

Comment: @KevinChoi I am simulating a binomial RV `x` in my project to get another RV `y` which is a function of `x`. However, `y` also has range `[0,n]`. In order to ensure that `y = f(x)` is within the acceptable range, a condition needs to be imposed on `x`, which boils down to choosing `x` binomially between `[a,b]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to collect all the values of `bin` in a pretty short time:

```
from scipy.special import comb
import numpy as np
def distribution(n, p=0.5):
    x = np.arange(n+1)
    return comb(n, x, exact=False) * p ** x * (1 - p) ** (n - x)
```

It can be done in a quarter of microsecond for `n=1000`.

**Sample run:**

```
>>> distribution(4):
array([0.0625, 0.25  , 0.375 , 0.25  , 0.0625])
```

You can sum specific parts of this array like so:

```
>>> np.sum(distribution(4)[2:4])
0.625
```

**Remark:** For `n>1000` middle values of this distribution requires to use extremely large numbers in multiplication therefore `RuntimeWarning` is raised.

#### Bugfix

You can use [`scipy.stats.binom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html) equivalently:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
def distribution(n, p):
    return binom.pmf(np.arange(n+1), n, p)
```

This does the same as above mentioned method quite efficiently (`n=1000000` in a third of second). Alternatively, you can use `binom.cdf(np.arange(n+1), n, p)` which calculate cumulative sum of `binom.pmf`. Then subtraction of `b`th and `a`th items of this array gives an output which is very close to what you expect.

Comment: Wow, this really seems to be quite fast. I wonder how they go about calculating `nCr` within the `binom` class so efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the CDF and it's inverse, something like:

```py
from scipy import stats

dist = stats.binom(100, 0.5)

# limit ourselves to [60, 100]
lo, hi = dist.cdf([60, 100])

# draw a sample
x = dist.ppf(stats.uniform(lo, hi-lo).rvs())
```

should give us values in the range.  note that due to floating point precision, this might give you values outside of what you want.  it gets worse above the mean of the distribution

note that for large values you might as well use the normal approximation